# Riddle of beneficial lies

Tags: riddle

> I was created to cleanse the earth,
>
> I was created to feed the poor.
>
> I was created to heal the mind,
>
> I was created from mens' fears and lies,
>
> I hold the power of many, yet I am no one.

What am I?

Hint:

> spiritual

Comment: Welcome to puzzling! Riddles which are too short are usually closed as 'Too  Broad' as they have multiple answers. Perhaps spend a bit more time on you riddles to make them better quality and with a definite answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

God?
[extra characters to fill out minimum]

Comment: I don't think God feeds the poor or heals the mind, but You are pretty close. Also God has his own power, but can be argued to be no one But yes, it gets a bit blurry. Wanna try again?

Comment: You said "created to feed the poor", not "feeds the poor". Are you thinking of something similar like religion?

Comment: Yes religion was the intended answer. But as I said it gets a bit blurry, I apologize.

Answer (score 2):

I was created to cleanse the earth:

> Trees and plants can cleanse the earth of toxins (it is called phytoremediation)
> Also it absorb odors and pollutant gases and provide Oxygen.

I was created to feed the poor.

> Trees provide food (fruit for humans)
> The poor can eat fruit from the jungle trees

What am I?

> Trees and plants

Hint:
(I was created to heal the mind)

> A walk in the woods is good for mind and body
> Exposure to trees and nature aids concentration by reducing mental fatigue.

Comment: This one is nice too, but it doesn't fit the title. You are taking it too litterally.

Answer (score 1):

It can be

> Water

I was created to cleanse the earth,

> Water/Rain cleanse the earth

I was created to feed the poor.

> Poor generally live on water.

Comment: That is not the "correct" intended answer, but I like it.

Comment: Maybe a few more hints will help.

Comment: the title is a hint too